# Using jQuery to set Title on attribute in parallel with CSS3 :after

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Hi i'm using this to set a title attribute on elements:

```
$('.upgradeTables thead tr td:gt(1)').attr('title', 'Upgrade To');
```

I'm then using CSS3 to do this:

```
.upgradeTables thead tr td:hover:before
{
    background: #000;
    content: attr(title);
    color: #f7f7f7;
    opacity: 0.95;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0.5px #333 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0.5px #333 !important;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0.5px #333 !important;
}
```

My question is, when i hover over the elements, the nicely CSS'd titles appear as i would like them and i can move along the TD's and "Upgrade To" appears above every one.

The problem is, when i hover over the first one, i get the CSS title but also the default grey browser title appear and stays visible as i move along to other TD's. How can i hide the default title popping up but still keep the CSS:after title visible on hover?

Comment: In what browser do you test it? In firefox I think it's ok http://jsfiddle.net/MKTbn/

Comment: Chrome. Haven't tested it elsewhere!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no simple CSS way of disabling tooltips with CSS. I'd suggest that using the title attribute in your example is not really semantic anyways (title attributes are meant to explain what's behind a link).

The alternative would be using [html5's data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), which would make your code look like...

```
$('.upgradeTables thead tr td:gt(1)').attr('data-tooltip', 'Upgrade To');
```

and your css declaration...

```
content: attr(data-tooltip);
```

Comment: Just a note, data-* attributes are not valid in pre-HTML5 specifications. But if the use case assumes HTML5, then data-*  attributes could be used instead of the title indeed.

Comment: It would work, it just wouldn't validate. I'd argue that if the OP is using such advanced CSS, then he's probably using an html5 doctype.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no way to prevent browsers from showing the tooltip with the `title` attribute. So, I would say, there is no chance for you to solve this with the approach you have currently.

What if, instead of setting the `title` attribute, you would simply insert the tooltips on `document.ready()`? This would give you **[more predictable code](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/nCqnS/)**. Just position the tooltip the way you need it and, I think, it should solve your issue.

**[jsFiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/nCqnS/)**